# In IntelliJ's XML editor, how to break a tag into multiple lines?

Tags: html, xml, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

When I have code like this (`|` represents a cursor):

```
<tag>|</tag>
```

and press enter, I get this:

```
<tag>
  |
</tag>
```

My question is, how can I quickly get from this:

```
<tag>text</tag>
```

to this:

```
<tag>
  text
</tag>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not a built in way to do this. However, if your markup is:

```
<tag>
    text</tag>
```

After running a code reformat (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) you will have this:

```
<tag>
    text
</tag>
```

You can take can take advantage of this in a macro. Off the top of my head, I can not think of a macro that will handle a single word value (without any spaces between the element tags and the value) and a multi-word value. Below is the macro that will do this for a multi-word value. For a single word value, you would drop step 2.  Place your cursor in the value/text area of the element. Start a macro recording (Edit > Macro >Start Recording) and record the following macro:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>  - Select word
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>  - Select the entire element value
3. <kbd>←</kbd> (Left Arrow) - move the cursor to the start of the selection, and thus at the end of the opening tag before the element value.
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>  - add a line break
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  - reformat code (opens dialog)
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>  - equivalent to clicking OK

Stop the macro recording, and name it. Then assign a keyboard shortcut to it (Settings > IDE Settings > Keymap > Macros)

Note that the above will run the reformat on the entire file. If you only want to run it on the tag in question, add three <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> commands between step 4 & 5 to select just that element and its value. Then add an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> before Step 6 (to ensure the "Selected Text" option in the dialog is always selectes).

Comment: thanks for that, I have used intelliJ for 9 years and never used macros before :)